# SQL Select from multiple tables Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, concatenation

I'm building a data extract from a SQL database. I have the following SQL query, which selects specific columns from multiple tables. The relationship that is problematic is this one:
I have a ConveyancingCondition table which has a foreign key to a ConveyancingDetail table which has a foreign key to a OTPSale table. It is possible for a record in OTPSale to have one ConveyancingDetail record with multiple ConveyancingCondition records.

I need to select the ConveyancingCondition fields separately, as well as combine them into a single string.

When I execute the select I receive multiple records for the same OTPSale. I know I need to group by conveyancingDetail but I get the group by error "Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.". I am selecting too many fields to add them all to the group by (atleast 50 different columns).

What is the correct way to do this?

```
select distinct
    --other fields from other tables
     (select FORMAT(conveyancingCondition.DateRequired, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
     where conveyancingCondition.Name = 'Deposit') 'Deposit Date Required',      
     (select FORMAT(conveyancingCondition.DateRequired, 'dd/MM/yyyy')       
     (select FORMAT(conveyancingCondition.DateRequired, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
     where conveyancingCondition.Name = 'Subject') 'Subject To Sale Date Required',     
     (select FORMAT(conveyancingCondition.DateRequired, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
     where conveyancingCondition.Name = 'Guarant') 'Guarantee Date Required',
    ISNULL(stuff((SELECT ( ',' + conveyancingCondition.DateRequired) FROM otp.ConveyancingCondition cd where (cd.ConveyancingDetailId = conveyancingDetail.Id AND cd.IsApplicable=1) FOR XML PATH( '' ) ), 1, 1, ''), NULL) as 'ConditionDates'

from otp.OTPSale    
left join otp.ConveyancingDetail conveyancingDetail 
on conveyancingDetail.Id = otp.OTPSale.ConveyancingDetailId
left join otp.ConveyancingCondition conveyancingCondition 
on conveyancingCondition.ConveyancingDetailId = conveyancingDetail.Id
WHERE otp.OTPSale.IsTransferRequired= 1 
--group by conveyancingDetail.Id
```

The data looks like this:

OTPSale

```
Id ConveyancingDetail IsTransferRequired
1  1                  1
2  2                  1
```

ConveyancingDetail

```
Id
1
2
3
```

ConveyancingCondition

```
Id  ConveyancingDetailId    Name    IsApplicable    DateRequired
1   1                       Deposit 1               2016-09-12      
2   1                       Bond    1               2016-09-26      
3   1                       Subject 1               2016-09-26        
4   1                       Guarant 1               2016-09-30      
5   1                       Other   0               NULL    
6   2                       Deposit 1               2016-09-15      
7   2                       Bond    1               2016-09-16      
8   2                       Subject 1               2016-09-17        
9   2                       Guarant 1               2016-09-18      
10  2                       Other   0               NULL
```

This is what I expect

```
OTPSaleId   Deposit Date Required   Bond Date Required  Subject Date Required   Guarantee Date Required     Other   ConditionDates

1           2016-09-12              2016-09-26          2016-09-26              2016-09-30              NULL    2016/09/22, 2016/09/26, 2016/09/26, 2016/09/30
2           2016-09-15              2016-09-16          2016-09-17              2016-09-18              NULL    2016/09/16, 2016/09/16, 2016/09/17, 2016/09/18
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: oops, forgot that, sql server - added in a tag

Answer (score 0):

Try conditional aggregate

```
select conveyancingDetail.Id
    --other fields from other tables
     max(case conveyancingCondition.Name when 'Deposit' then FORMAT(conveyancingCondition.DateRequired, 'dd/MM/yyyy') end) [Deposit Date Required],      
     max(case conveyancingCondition.Name when 'Subject' then FORMAT(conveyancingCondition.DateRequired, 'dd/MM/yyyy') end) [Subject To Sale Date Required],     
     --...

from otp.OTPSale    
left join otp.ConveyancingDetail conveyancingDetail 
on conveyancingDetail.Id = otp.OTPSale.ConveyancingDetailId
left join otp.ConveyancingCondition conveyancingCondition 
on conveyancingCondition.ConveyancingDetailId = conveyancingDetail.Id
WHERE otp.OTPSale.IsTransferRequired= 1 
group by conveyancingDetail.Id
```